# Ruby On Rails : PdfKit Runtime Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

pdfkit gem successfully installed in my machine. Then I run `gem install wkhtmltopdf-binary` and output was

```
Successfully installed wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.9.9.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.9.9.1...
unable to convert "\xC0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_386, skipping
unable to convert "\xA3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_x64, skipping
unable to convert "\xCE" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/wkhtmltopdf_darwin_386, skipping
Installing RDoc documentation for wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.9.9.1...
unable to convert "\xC0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_386, skipping
unable to convert "\xA3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_x64, skipping
unable to convert "\xCE" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/wkhtmltopdf_darwin_386, skipping
```

Well, then tried to access the pdf version of my page. But it also showed me an error
**Runtime Error ControllerName#show**

```
command failed: "/home/yasir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/wkhtmltopdf" "--page-size" "Letter" "--margin-top" "0.75in" "--margin-right" "0.75in" "--margin-bottom" "0.75in" "--margin-left" "0.75in" "--encoding" "UTF-8" "--quiet" "-" "-
```

"

Answer (score 1):

Add wkhtmltopdf installation path in your pdfkit configuration file (config/initializers/pdfkit.rb) as below

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  # Download compatible version of wkhtmltopdf from 'http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html'
  # Install it in your system.
  # Then run 'which wkhtmltopdf' in your terminal to identify the path and update it below
  config.wkhtmltopdf = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
end
```